# Should we consider the hotspot about unique index of Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I’m designing the table for Cloud Spanner.
According to the document, we need to consider the hotspot when create the primary key.
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design?hl=en

However I’m not sure that we need to consider the hotspot about unique index too.
Should we consider the hotspot about unique index of Spanner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indexes are implemented the same way as tables in Cloud Spanner and have the same performance considerations.

Comment: Thank you.
I'll try design while considering the hotspot.